# Script to Set LocalHostName failed with Invalid argument

Tags: macos, shell

Running on macOS (10.14 and up) I am using a shell scrip I found to:
Present a input window for a new computer name and then have it change the following:
**ComputerName,**
**HostName,**
**LocalHostName.**
The script keeps failing with the following error:
*SCPreferencesSetLocalHostName() failed: Invalid argument*.
When I remove the line - `scutil --set LocalHostName "$MacName"`
The scrip runs with out error.
Something within how I am having it accessing the LocalHostName is not correct.

````
defaults=/usr/bin/defaults

CurrentUser=$(/usr/sbin/scutil <<< "show State:/Users/ConsoleUser" | awk '/Name :/ && ! /loginwindow/ {print $3}')
MacName=$(sudo -u "$CurrentUser" /usr/bin/osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to set MacName to text returned of (display dialog "Enter the new Computer Name:" buttons "Continue" default button "Continue" default answer "" with icon 1)')

scutil --set ComputerName "$MacName"
scutil --set HostName "$MacName"
scutil --set LocalHostName "$MacName"
defaults write /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.smb.server NetBIOSName -string "$MacName"

/usr/bin/dscacheutil -flushcache```
````

Comment: Can you add a line a-la `echo "$MacName" | xxd -g1` to see what the returned text looks like, including any unexpected characters, and share that?

Comment: What are you trying to set as a computer name? I haven't tested this, but I wouldn't be surprised if things like spaces in the name could cause an error like this.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same script and issue (actually joined stackoverflow to answer this, so i'm sorry for inproper use of the answer box)

my script has "computer-$variable" instead of "$variable" and does computer-.localizedvariable for the computer name.

Does your script maybe put out .localizedvariable?

I suggest it tries to do the same for localhostname but localhostname doesn't like anything except " - "

If i run the script locally it works fine, but with the MDM it does this error.

Answer (score 1):

Running the command outside of a script I found that removing .local from the end seemed to have resolved the issue for me.
incorrect command:
sudo scutil --set LocalHostName Name.local

correct command:
sudo scutil --set LocalHostName Name

hope this helps